# Display data by id from database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

My name is Boonsita. I have some question about PHP code.
I have a home.html file call showWord.php using ajax. When we click link from home.html and then link to word.html .
   However, I need to display word in word.html by id from home.html

I hope you can understand, Than you so much.
Following code

home.html

```
<body onload="showWords()">
<div class="container">
    <div id="showWord">
        <!--show data in this-->
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showWords() {
      //alert ("Hello");
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request php
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://172.28.80.227/senior-project/std-56/370-593/Demo/showWord.php",
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#showWord").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

showWord.php

```
<body>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
              <ul class="list-group">
                    <a href="word.html?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="list-group-item"><h1><?php echo $row["word"] ?></h1></a>
              </ul>
  <?php
      }
    }
      else
    {
      ?>
          <br><br>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ไม่มีข้อมูลคำศัพท์
              </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <?php
    }
  ?>
</div>
```

word.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="showWord">
        <!--show data in this-->
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Word() {
     console.log($(".input_text"));
      //alert ("Hello");
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request php
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://172.28.80.227/senior-project/std-56/370-593/Demo/word.php",
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#showWord").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

word.php

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
              <ul class="list-group">
                    <a href="word.html?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="list-group-item"><h1><?php echo $row["word"] ?></h1></a>
              </ul>
  <?php
      }
    }
      else
    {
      ?>
          <br><br>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; ไม่มีข้อมูลคำศัพท์
              </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <?php
    }
  ?>
</div>
```